# Extracting files at the start up setup instead of the end

Tags: installation, deployment, inno-setup

I am using the latest version of inno that does the following during setup:

1. Perform dependency check to see what is installed
2. Installs dependencies that are not already installed (.net, sql server, directx etc)
3. Install the application and the files from the [Files] section (wpReady)
4. Checks SQL Server for previously installed database and creates / updates the tables etc

Step [4] creates the database and tables etc and only works if SQL Server has already been installed which is why it is done in Step [2].

The output directory contains the created setup.exe and I manually place the additional dependencies folder containing the files required for steps [1,2 and 4] mentioned above.

This works great but I would like to create a single exe only that includes all the dependencies and extracts the dependencies BEFORE `wpReady` and before Step [1] above.

The dependencies are in the `[Files]` section but these files are not extracted until the setup executes `wpReady` message after the setup has gone through all the forms and attempts to install the files.

I use the following that adds what I need to the setup.exe

```
[Files]
Source: Output\Dependencies\*; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: deleteafterinstall
```

What is the best way to extract the files to the temp directory before `wpReady` or should I perform the actions of `wpReady` first then go about installing the Dependencies (not ideal though).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `ExtractTemporaryFile()` function in the `PrepareToInstall` event function to extract any file from the `[Files]` section to `{tmp}` earlier, and it will be deleted when the setup finishes. Together with scripting and the various hooks Inno Setup gives you nearly everything can be achieved.

Have a look at the "Pascal Scripting" section of the Inno Setup help, specifically the "Support Functions Reference". There you will find documentation for `ExtractTemporaryFile()` and more.

Comment: The recomended place to do this is now in the [PrepareToInstall] event function as it allows for easier warnign of uses and restart prompts.

Answer (score -2):

{tmp}

Temporary directory used by Setup or Uninstall. This is not the value of the user's TEMP environment variable. It is a subdirectory of the user's temporary directory which is created by Setup or Uninstall at startup (with a name like "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\IS-xxxxx.tmp"). All files and subdirectories in this directory are deleted when Setup or Uninstall exits. During Setup, this is primarily useful for extracting files that are to be executed in the [Run] section but aren't needed after the installation.

Comment: Not only your response does not indicate clearly what you suggest to change in the script, assuming you want to say to use the {tmp} file location as destination, @Belliez question states s/he want's to extract the files before the actual installation process begin, and the way I read your suggestion it will put the files there after that moment.

Comment: thats what i get from help  beacuse i dont undestand  ExtractTemporaryFile()  and i cant make it  if you can please give me an example
 thanks