# Extract multiple files from installer before installation begins in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

**I have few SQL script files which have to run before installation begin. The reason is if SQL scripts run successfully only, I want to do the installation.**

If the SQL scripts need to run after the installation, I can copy the files to `{app}` path and run the files from there. But the requirement is run the files before installation begins. I am confused. What is the best way of doing it?

Say for example if it is a single file I can put it under `Files` section and can use `ExtractTemporaryFile('FileName');`

But as I mentioned, I have many files (in `SQLSCRIPTS` folder). What is the better way? (One solution is I can make it as a single file by zipping it and then unzip it)

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\\SQLSCRIPTS\\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: dontcopy
```

Comment: Usually, before data being copied to destination directory, it will be copied to a temporary directory. You can run these scripts at this point, and then exit if the script failed. It is impossible to suggest a solution without looking at code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting files at the start up setup instead of the end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797888/extracting-files-at-the-start-up-setup-instead-of-the-end)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl please check my edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract multiple files from installer, use the [`ExtractTemporaryFiles`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extracttemporaryfiles), like:

```pascal
ExtractTemporaryFiles('*.sql');
```